# How to generate higher value in entity generator instead of standard value 1?

Tags: matlab, entity, generator, simulink

I am new to Simulink in Matlab and I am looking to generate higher value in entity generator. I need to have constant 100 people right from start time.

By default, the entity generator in Simulink generates "1", but I need to generate higher value.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For an example, see the `Burst Entity Generation - Generating Multiple Entities Simultaneously` section of the documentation: [Generating and Initializing Entities](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/examples/generating-and-initializing-entities.html)